# Почему this в объекте не работает?

Tags: javascript

Почему this.port выдает - *Cannot read property 'port' of undefined*

```
const obj = {
  server: "ru-RU",
  port: 3000,
  startServer: () => console.log(`Servert starting, port: ${this.port}`)
};

obj.startServer();
```

А если пытаюсь привязать контекст, то вовсе получаю **undefinde**, что-то не так с стрелочными функциями? С обычными функциями все работает

Answer (score 9, accepted):

у стрелочных функций нет своего `this`, по-этому стрелочная функция, при выполнении, ищет контекст (`this`) в **ближайшей родительской функции** и использует его. если и там его нет, то поиск продолжается по цепочке (`Scope`) дальше.

если же ближайшей родительской функции вовсе нет - то контекстом будет является наш любимый `window / global`, как в Вашем случае

вот [здесь](https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/428566/) почитайте